# Phonegap show html if not connected

Tags: ios, cordova

Here is my code at the minute:

Using phonegap 2.9

```
    <head>

</head>
<body>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

        // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log("Device Ready");
        }

    // Handle the online event
    //
    function onOnline() {
        document.location = 'http://app.dadad.com';
    }

    function onOffline() {
        console.log("Offline");
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

However right now I just get a white screen whether i'm connected or not. Eventually what I would like is to display some html when the user is not connected.

So in conclusion:

1. Would like to fix the function as it is not working
2. Would like to show html when not connected.

Comment: Did you try `window.location.href` instead of `document.location`?

Comment: Tried that. Its not an issue with that - its an issue with the actual function.

Comment: Is there a way to check if(document.location = 'http://app.dadad.com' has not loaded){ alert("no connection");

Answer (score 0):

The Online/Offline events do not fire onload. They are there for when you are in app (complete load) and then lose or gain connection. I have gotten around this by doing an initial connection check on load, like this:

```
function checkConnetcion() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
    var connectionStatus = states[networkState];
    if(connectionStatus) {
        //Do something if connected
    }
    else{
        //Do something if not connected
    }
}
```

Then add this your onready function:

```
    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("Device Ready");
        checkConnetcion();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so I did that. Its still not working. Is there I've missed out? Ive included the cordova.js right after opening the <body> tag then included your function below. I still get a white screen though.

Comment: updated my answer, did you add the function call to `onDeviceReady`? Also, I just noticed you are trying to set the location to an external address. have you tried just alerting something to see if the call is working?

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. I added the onready function below the check connection function. I changed the code to alert instead of setting the location to an external address. Strange. It should be working

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Jquery ajax and send a dummy request before sending actual request. If you get and Error Code as '0' it means there is no internet connectivity.

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'TestUrl',
 type: 'GET',
 success: function (data) {
            // Go ahead with you request
 },
 error: function (x, y, z) {
    if (x.status == 0) {
        alert("Please connect to the internet");
    }
   else{
       alert("Other Error Occured")
    }
 }
});
```

Secondly you can also make you of HTML 5 navigator

```
var condition = navigator.onLine ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE";
```

But it will show **ONLINE** when **WIFI doesn't provide Internet connection**.
**Cordova connection object will also show WIFI if there is no internet connection**

Comment: Thanks. Im still getting a white screen. I think it has something to do with the jquery. When I just do alert("test"); it alerts. However when I add ajax it doesn't.

Comment: As u dont have anything in HTML body its showing white screen!!! Add jquery reference and also try wrapping this code in document.ready function

Comment: Ive done all of that : `    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
               url: 'http://app.dada.com',
               type: 'GET',
               success: function (data) {
               document.location = "http://app.dada.com";
               },
               error: function (x, y, z) {
               if (x.status == 0) {
               alert("Please connect to the internet");
               }
               else{
               alert("Other Error Occured")
               }
               }
               });
               });

    
        </script>`

Comment: Ru referncing the script in body or head tag

Comment: Update: I managed to get it to show the document.location, but the error alert is not working.